# Windows Update failed to install on Windows 10 because of Mass Storage disabled

Tags: windows-update, wsus

I have a problem with Windows Updates on Windows 10 machines.

We use the Windows 10 Professional Version:2004 operating system.
The updates handled by our WSUS server. (Windows Server 2019)

The latest cumulative updates (2020-06 - KB4557957,2020-07 - KB4565503) are failed to install.

In the windows eventlog there is an entry which tells you to: Package KB4565503 (or KB4557957) failed to be changed to the Installed state. Status: 0x80070005.

I've tried several solutions like:

- Windows Update troubleshooter
- SoftwareDistrubution folder rename, delete etc.
- Disable, remove antivirus software
- changing services startup (wuauserv,cryptSvc,bits,trustedinstaller)
- Update from Microsoft Update directly
- Manual download these updates from Microsoft Catalog and install

All of these method are failed.

The symptom is the following. After I reboot the computer it appears a black screen during boot time, nothing else.

The only solution is hard reset several times and if I have luck the updates will be rolled back.

In our system there is a GPO which disable USB drives automatically.

If I create a computer object in AD and deny this GPO before I put a new computer into the domain, the updates will be installed successfully through WSUS.

If I just do this the normal way the GPO applied the updates are failed to install.

Any helps appreciated.

Comment: 0x80070005 error code is "Access Denied"! Please check if the "Trusted Installer" has permission on the file `usbstor.inf` (very important)... The problem can be analysed if you can share the relevant parts of CBS.log which highlights the error.

Comment: Hi. 
    The owner of C:\Windows\INF\usbstor.inf file is NT Service\TrustedInstaller.    
    The relevant content of CBS.log:   
    2020-08-24 10:59:50, Error                 CBS    Doqe: Failed staging driver     updates [HRESULT = 0x80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED]  
    2020-08-24 10:59:50, Error                 CBS    Failed staging drivers, rebooting     and trying again [HRESULT = 0x80070005 - E_ACCESSDENIED]

Comment: Please share the permission for the "Trusted Installer", which should have permission of Full control on the file usbstor.inf (very important)... Also, please share the few lines (15~20 lines) above of previous error message and insert in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

- Log in as administrator to the machine. Navigate to c:\windows\inf.
- Changed the owner of usbstor.inf to builtin\administrators.
- Restart the machine.
- Edit the security and set to inherit from parent folder.
- Remove non inherited rights from the file.
- Install the remaining updates.

Thanks @Am_I_Helpful!